# How to remove input field that was inserted via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

Someone please help me how to add new function to remove the field, i have js script function that add new field as follows

```
<script language="javascript">
fields = 0;
function addInput() {
    if (fields != 10) {
        var htmlText =  "&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='text' name='friends[]' value='' size='auto' maxlength='45' /><br />";
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.id = 'new_field';
        newElement.innerHTML = htmlText;

        var fieldsArea = document.getElementById('new_field');
        fieldsArea.appendChild(newElement);
        fields += 1;

    } else {
        alert("Only 10 fields allowed.");
        document.form.add.disabled=true;
    }
} 
</script>
```

but i need some helps to add new functions for removing field, For any suggestion and pointer I Would be appreciate.

Comment: if you add some ids to the "div" it will be easyer to get them for removal.

Comment: You cannot have ` newElement.id = 'new_field';` because every id on the page has to be unique. Add something that is unique to your id. I suggest something like this: declare outside the function a variable count = 0 ; every time you add a new input count++; `newElement.id = 'new_field'+count`

Comment: Nice Suggestion Octopus-Paul, well i Replace: newElement.id = 'new_field'; with: newElement.id = 'new_field'+(fields+1);, this also work fine at most browser except IE, but I am not sure that i was correct, need more pointer, Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read here about removeChild() function [removeChild() - mozilla developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/traversing_an_html_table_with_javascript_and_dom_interfaces#Removing_nodes_with_the_removeChild%28..%29_method)

Edit Or here: [removeChild() w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/met_element_removechild.asp)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's already one problem I see with your code. You are setting each new field's ID to the same value, which is invalid HTML and asking for trouble. Be sure to fix that.

The [`.removeChild` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) of DOM elements is what you want. `.removeChild` will remove a node (element or text) from the DOM tree (the set of elements actually contained within the document) only if the node passed in is actually a child of that element, otherwise an error occurs.

You can easily remove the last field by finding the [last child](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.lastChild) of its container:

```
function removeLastField() {
    var fieldsArea = document.getElementById('new_field'),
        lastChild = fieldsArea.lastChild;
    if(lastChild) {
        fieldsArea.removeChild(lastChild);
        fields -= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi idealmachine, i did your explanation, but seem not work yet, about to set id to unique id, i was try replace: ewElement.id = 'new_field'; with: newElement.id = 'new_field'+1; that correct? please do not hesitate to give more suggestions, and Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not correct to put `newElement.id = 'new_field'+1` because all the ids will be new_field1. Your ids should be something like new_field1, new_field2 ....